# Fetch Data from Router

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My friend and I are planing to make an chrome extension to search devices connected to the same router and display it on the extension user interface.

But I'm not sure that we are able to do it. I tried to search online. I didn't find any information I want.

Can we be able to build such extension? If we can, could you give a direction or useful tutorials. Thanks

Comment: some routers have the function to list connected network devices through tr064 upnp protocol

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your task is to scan local area network, which does not sound too complicated. Since you are building an extension for Chrome, you are going to realize it in JS. Have a look at
[this project.](https://github.com/AllGloryToTheHypnotoad/nodescan)

This repo has almost everything you'll need.